On Wikipedia's Proof of Cauchy's Integral Theorem from Green's Theorem
I struggle to understand two steps in Wikipedia's proof of Cauchy's Integral Theorem

Assuming -for simplicity- that $\gamma$ is non-self-intersecting, what exactly is the definition of the region $D$ bounded by $\gamma$? Intuitively, it may be defined as the collection of complex numbers which winding number (with respect to $\gamma$) is nonzero, but then it is not trivial that this is a $2$-dimensional manifold with boundary $\gamma$.

How do we deal with the case when $\gamma$ is self-intersecting? I'd guess the idea is to 'chop' $\gamma$ into multiple non-self-intersecting curves, but these need not be smooth at the endpoints, and thus would not be defining a $1$-dimensional manifold.



Wikipedia doesn’t really prove much/handle the difficult cases. It is simply proving that

if $f(z)$ is holomorphic and has continuous first partials, and $D$ is any bounded open set with smooth boundary, then $\int_{\partial D}f(z)\,dz=0$.

In other words, they’re simply assuming all the conditions needed in order for a one line application of Stokes’ theorem (smooth forms, bounded open set with smooth boundary)… or Green’s theorem as it’s more commonly known in this 2-dimensional case. So, although they make it sound as if they’re starting with a $\gamma$, they’re really starting with a $D$ and saying the integral over the boundary is $0$.
More generally, we have the following result:

Let $\omega$ be a $C^1$ differential $k$-form on a smooth manifold $M$. Then, $d\omega=0$ if and only if for all ‘nice’ $(k+1)$-dimensional manifolds with boundary $D$ in $M$, we have $\int_{\partial D}\omega=0$.

To prove $(\implies)$ we use Stokes’ theorem: $\int_{\partial D}=\int_{D}d\omega=\int_D0=0$ (this is also the only direction Wikipedia is concerned with). To prove the converse $(\impliedby)$, note that for all such $D$, we have $\int_Dd\omega=\int_{\partial D}\omega=0$, and so by a small variant of the fundamental lemma of calculus of variations, it follows that $d\omega=0$.

If you want to properly deal with the more general cases, and also dispense with the hypothesis of continuous first partials of a holomorphic function, then you’re going to need to get your hands dirty with some technical lemmas about homotopy of curves, and primitives of (continuous) locally-exact forms along curves. These details can all be found in Henri-Cartan’s complex analysis book. The idea of trying to ‘chop up’ your curve into a bunch of pieces, each of which is bounding something is just a pain to make precise (and I’ve never seen any book do this sufficiently carefully for sufficiently general $\gamma$).
